# How does List.max<'T> work?

Tags: f#, type-constraints, parametric-polymorphism

From MSDN docs, the signature of `List.max` is:

```
List.max : 'T list -> 'T (requires comparison)
```

My questions are:

- How does compiler statically verify that `'T` supports comparison operation?
- Is `requires` a keyword to specify type constraints? If yes, what all types of constraints can I specify with it?
- Can I define my own kinds of constraints, like I can do with typeclasses in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at this blog from Don Syme: [Equality and Comparison Constraints in F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx)

you can think of those contraints as a form of type-classes light, normaly overriding Equals/GetHashCode and implementing IComparable is sufficient to use it in this cases.

To your questions:

1. yes the compiler will check this
2. yes exactly, look at the F# [specifications](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html) / [Docu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203%28VS.100%29.aspx) for more details
3. kind of - you can contraint to interfaces and that like - see the articles

PS: the (requires comparison) is defined by saying `<'a when 'a : comparison>` in the context of a generic definition like

```
type MyType<'a when 'a : comparision>
```

Answer (score 2):

Carsten's answer covers most of the bases.  Regarding declaring the constraint, in most cases you don't need to declare it since it will be inferred by any use of a comparison operator.  For instance:

```
let myListMax l = l |> List.reduce (fun x y -> if x > y then x else y)
// or myListMax l = l |> List.reduce max
```

As Carsten said, if you want to explicitly annotate the definition with the constraint you can do it like this:

```
let myListMax (l:'a list) : 'a when 'a : comparison = l |> List.reduce max
```